Error: could not build wheels for reppy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I'm trying to install the spidy command from GitHub "https://github.com/rivermont/spidy" on Linux and on my VSC
but I keep getting this error on both Linux and VSC:
"error: could not build wheels for reppy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Can anyone help me with this issue?
I tried updating pip and reinstalling it. I also tried this method:
python3 -m pip install python-dev-tools --user --upgrade

But it didn't work for me.

At first, You should downgrade python's version 3.8.20
So You can build reppy by pip install
